# Show/Hide Combobox Dropdown with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, combobox, user-controls

I have a user control in asp.net that outputs markup similar to the following:

```
<div id="combobox1">
  <div id="combobox1_text"><span>combobox 1</span></div>
  <div id="combobox1_ddl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$1" />
    <label for="combobox1_$1">Item 1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$2" />
    <label for="combobox1_$2">Item 2</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$3" />
    <label for="combobox1_$3">Item 3</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$4" />
    <label for="combobox1_$4">Item 4</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$5" />
    <label for="combobox1_$5">Item 5</label>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

A javascript file accompanying this control has the following class (minimal code to reproduce the problem only):

```
ComboBox = function(cb) {
  var pnlContainer = document.getElementById(cb);
  var pnlComboBox = document.getElementById(cb + '_text');
  var pnlDropdownList = document.getElementById(cb + '_ddl');
  var isCollapsed = true;

  var collapseDropdown = function() {
    if (!isCollapsed) {
      isCollapsed = true;
      pnlDropdownList.style.display = 'none';
      //-- some more custom handling code follows here --
    }
  };
  pnlComboBox.onclick = function() {
    isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
    pnlDropdownList.style.display = (isCollapsed) ? 'none' : 'block';
  };
  pnlContainer.onclick = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  };
  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    collapseDropdown();
  }, false);
}
```

And finally, on my page I create an instance of the class like this:

```
cb1 = new ComboBox('combobox1');
```

All this works fine until there is only one instance of this control. It collapses correctly whenever anything or anywhere outside the control is clicked, just as expected.

**The Problem:**

The problem happens when there are more than one instances of this control on the page. If one of the comboboxes is open, and user clicks on another instance of my combobox, the previous one doesn't collapse.

JsFiddle for minimal code to reproduce the problem can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/x8qjo79f/

I know it is happening because of `event.stopPropagation()` call, but don't know what to do for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the document onclick event listener to capture the event (so it is executed before the bubbling phase) and collapse when its target is outside your combobox.

```js
ComboBox = function(cb) {
  var pnlContainer = document.getElementById(cb);
  var pnlComboBox = document.getElementById(cb + '_text');
  var pnlDropdownList = document.getElementById(cb + '_ddl');
  var isCollapsed = true;

  var collapseDropdown = function() {
    if (!isCollapsed) {
      isCollapsed = true;
      pnlDropdownList.style.display = 'none';
      //-- some more custom handling code follows here --
    }
  };
  pnlComboBox.onclick = function() {
    isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
    pnlDropdownList.style.display = (isCollapsed) ? 'none' : 'block';
  };
  pnlContainer.onclick = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  // Edit: Capture click event
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (!pnlContainer.contains(event.target)) collapseDropdown();
  }, true);
}

cb1 = new ComboBox('combobox1');
cb2 = new ComboBox('combobox2');
```

```css
#combobox1,
#combobox2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: default;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#combobox1_text,
#combobox2_text {
  padding: 2px;
}

#combobox1_ddl,
#combobox2_ddl {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="combobox1">
  <div id="combobox1_text"><span>combobox 1</span></div>
  <div id="combobox1_ddl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$1" />
    <label for="combobox1_$1">Item 1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$2" />
    <label for="combobox1_$2">Item 2</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$3" />
    <label for="combobox1_$3">Item 3</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$4" />
    <label for="combobox1_$4">Item 4</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox1_$5" />
    <label for="combobox1_$5">Item 5</label>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<input type="text" />
<br />
<input type="button" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />
<br />
<span>some random text in the document.. <br />blah. blah.. blah..</span>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="combobox2">
  <div id="combobox2_text"><span>combobox 2</span></div>
  <div id="combobox2_ddl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox2_$1" />
    <label for="combobox2_$1">Item 1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox2_$2" />
    <label for="combobox2_$2">Item 2</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox2_$3" />
    <label for="combobox2_$3">Item 3</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox2_$4" />
    <label for="combobox2_$4">Item 4</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="combobox2_$5" />
    <label for="combobox2_$5">Item 5</label>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I originally had the dropdown collapse on `onblur` event. The problem is with chrome browser where it collapses the dropdown as soon as a checkbox in the dropdown area is clicked. I want it to be open until the user clicks anywhere outside the combobox or, collapses it by clicking the combobox text area.

Comment: I revised my answer

Comment: Very good. I observed that I no longer need the `event.stopPropagation()` call after this and can completely get rid of the `pnlContainer.onclick` event handling.

Answer (score 2):

You could allow the event propagation in `pnlContainer.onclick` but remember that the ComboBox was clicked. Inside the document click event handler, you would test if the ComboBox is the clicked one, and allow to collapse only if it is not.

The changes to the Javascript code could look like this:

```
ComboBox = function(cb) {
  var isClicked = false;
  ...
  pnlContainer.onclick = function(event) {
    isClicked = true;
  };
  document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (isClicked) {
      isClicked = false;
    }
    else {
      collapseDropdown();
    }
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Nice trick to get rid of `event.stopPropagation()` call. I had probably been looking in one direction only.